# How to hide columns in dynamic subranges before converttohtml in emailbody in Outlook?

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook, hidden

I am doing a macro that is formatting a data base into a table, and then select ranges from this table in order to send to different persons depending of the range.

But depending of the range sometimes I can have several column empty, I would like to add in my loop that when creating the temporary workbook, to copy paste my subtable that I wanna send, a function or a part that check if the column is empty (I have headers) and if it's the case, hide the columns concerned only for this range and then convert to HTML in my body email the range without my empty column now hidden and after the loop keeps going through my whole table.

Thanks to a previous post, my VBA code is running smoothly but as soon as I add the part which is supposed to hide column, it's not working anymore, I guess, that I am not adding it in the right place but I don't know,

I tried to add it, just after `RangeToEmail` and in the function that is creating the `tempWB`, `RangetoHTML` but it's not working. (see both codes after)

The code I used on a static range and which is working, to hide the column is

```vb
Dim iFirstCol As Integer, iLastCol As Integer, i As Integer`

'variables to hold the first and last column numbers    
iFirstCol = Range("A2").Column    
iLastCol = Range("W2").Column
LastRow = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))

'count backwards through columns    
For i = iLastCol To iFirstCol Step -1    
    'if all cells are blank, hide the column    
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(LastRow, i))) = 0 Then
        Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True    
    End If    
Next i
```

and here is the code I use to go from my table to the different subtable and then through TemporaryWB convert to html in my email body

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetNames()    
    Dim NameArray() As String    
    Dim NameRange As Range    
    Dim C As Range    
    Dim Counter As Integer    
    Dim NameFilter As Variant    
    Dim RangeToEmail As Range    
    Dim EmailAddress() As String

    'Email Stuff    
    Dim objOutlook As Object    
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

    Dim objEmail As Object    
    Set NameRange = Range(Range("H2"), Range("H2").End(xlDown))    
    ReDim NameArray(1 To Range(Range("H2"), Range("H2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count) ReDim EmailAddress(1 To Range(Range("H2"), Range("H2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count)    
    Counter = 0

    For Each C In NameRange    
        Counter = Counter + 1    
        NameArray(Counter) = C.Value    
        EmailAddress(Counter) = C.Offset(, 3)    
    Next

    NameArray = ArrayRemoveDups(NameArray)    
    EmailAddress = ArrayRemoveDups(EmailAddress)    
    Counter = 0

    For Each NameFilter In NameArray    
        Counter = Counter + 1    
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=NameFilter Set RangeToEmail = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTable").Range   

        Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)   
        With objEmail .To = EmailAddress(Counter)    
            .Subject = "TestSubject"    
            .HTMLBody = "Hello, <br><br>Please see the latest report:<br><br>" & RangetoHTML(RangeToEmail)    
            .Display
        End With
        Set objEmail = Nothing   
    Next

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter 
End Sub


Function ArrayRemoveDups(MyArray As Variant) As Variant    
    Dim nFirst As Long, nLast As Long, i As Long    
    Dim item As String    
    Dim arrTemp() As String   
    Dim Coll As New Collection

    'Get First and Last Array Positions    
    nFirst = LBound(MyArray)    
    nLast = UBound(MyArray)    
    ReDim arrTemp(nFirst To nLast)

    'Convert Array to String    
    For i = nFirst To nLast    
        arrTemp(i) = CStr(MyArray(i))    
    Next i

    'Populate Temporary Collection    
    On Error Resume Next

    For i = nFirst To nLast    
        Coll.Add arrTemp(i), arrTemp(i)    
    Next i

    Err.Clear   
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Resize Array    
    nLast = Coll.Count + nFirst - 1    
    ReDim arrTemp(nFirst To nLast) '    
    Populate Array

    For i = nFirst To nLast    
        arrTemp(i) = Coll(i - nFirst + 1)    
    Next i

    'Output Array    
    ArrayRemoveDups = arrTemp    
End Function


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)    
    Dim fso As Object    
    Dim ts As Object    
    Dim TempFile As String    
    Dim TempWB As Workbook    
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    ' Copy the range and create a workbook to receive the data.    
    rng.Copy    
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)

    With TempWB.Sheets(1)    
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8    
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False    
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False    
        .Cells(1).Select    
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        On Error Resume Next    
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True    
        .DrawingObjects.Delete    
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    ' Publish the sheet to an .htm file.    
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _ SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _ Filename:=TempFile, _ Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _ Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _ HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic) 
        .Publish (True)    
    End With

    ' Read all data from the .htm file into the RangetoHTML subroutine.    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)

    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll    
    ts.Close RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _ "align=left x:publishsource=")

    ' Close TempWB. TempWB.Close savechanges:=False    
    ' Delete the htm file.    
    Kill TempFile    
    Set ts = Nothing    
    Set fso = Nothing    
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Note that *"it's not working anymore"* is no usefull error description. Which errors do you get and where? And which part in your code produces the issue? Also see if you could provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: I don’t get any error, it either produces my mail empty or the whole data base and not the sub range or the subrange with missing columns (not empty)

Comment: It cannot produce "mail empty **or** the whole data base and not the sub range or the subrange with missing columns (not empty)", I am afraid. The same code, working on the same sheet should produce the same result...

Comment: Yes, it was regarding the part that I changed the place of the part about hiding column in the whole code

Answer (score 0):

First `LastRow` is not declared as variable properly and therfore you didn't see that

```
LastRow = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
```

is actually writing an array of values into `LastRow`. Actually your first code cannot work properly. Make sure you use `Option Explicit` (I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*).

The issue is probably if your empty columns have headers too then

```
WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(LastRow, i)))
```

will never be `0` because you included your header row 1 `Cells(1, i)` in your range. So if you want to exclude the header you need to change it to start with row `2` like `Cells(2, i)`.

Finally all this code applies to `ActiveSheet` which is not very reliable because the active sheet can change by a single mouse click. If you can specify the worksheet precisely by a name, do so. If it really has to run on multiple sheets (so you really want to use the active one) at least make sure the active sheet does not change during the code excecutes by reading it only once into a variable `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet`.

I would use

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'name your sheet here!

'or if it really is the active sheet do
'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'and make sure you only use `ws` from now!

'variables to hold the first and last column numbers    
Dim iFirstCol As Long
iFirstCol = ws.Columns("A").Column 

Dim iLastCol As Long
iLastCol = ws.Columns("W").Column

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row


'count backwards through columns
Dim i As Long    
For i = iLastCol To iFirstCol Step -1    
    'if all cells are blank, hide the column    
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(LastRow, i))) = 0 Then
        ws.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True    
    End If    
Next i
```

Apply the same to the rest of your code to make it more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will do that, and where do you suggest I implement this part in the whole code ?

Comment: @LéaV I meant you should apply the technique specifying the worksheet for every `Range`, `Cells`, `Columns` and `Rows` object like I did. Otherwise Excel cannot know for sure which worksheet you mean. It might guess wrong.

Comment: No yes sure, I was talking about the part to hide column in each temporary worksheet before converting it to HTML and pasting it in the outlook mail body

Comment: @LéaV Then I didn't understand what you mean by *"implement this part in the whole code"*. Why don't you test it?

Comment: When I have my data base formatted as I wish, after that I run the code that split my table in different sub range and each of them is sent to different person, this part is already working, however, I have some columns in the sub ranges that are empty and I would like to implement the code that hide empty column, in the one that is created my sub ranges. Like this, i would have my mails created as it’s already doing but for each one, if I have maybe 3 columns empty for only that subrange, it hides them before converting them to html and putting it in outlook.

Comment: Right now the part to hide column is before defining my RangeToEmail variable, and it produces my mail but with my empty column as the code was not here